# Send a message with inline keyboard using Telegram.Bot C#

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

All I want is to send a message with inline keyboard using Telegram.Bot package.
I have a bot, now I need a code that sends a message with one inline button. Button click should open a link.

Answer (score 0):

Use `InlineKeyboardMarkup`, and pass it in `SendTextMessageAsync` method in `replyMarkup` parameter, Or with any send message method, here is an example:

```
InlineKeyboardButton button = InlineKeyboardButton.WithUrl("Text", "https://www.google.com/");

InlineKeyboardMarkup keyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(button);

await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chat, "My message text", replyMarkup: keyboard);
```